# Colour points in a scatter plot by position (matplotlib)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, slice

I have a diagram of stars from a stellar catalog, showing luminosity against temperature:

```
from astroML.datasets import fetch_sdss_sspp as fetch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = fetch()
print("Data contains %d objects" % data.shape)
print("Column names are %s" % str(data.dtype.names[:])[1:-1])

data = data[:10000]
rpsf = data['rpsf'] # make some reasonable cuts
data = data[(rpsf > 15) & (rpsf < 19)]
logg = data['logg']
Teff = data['Teff']

blue_branch = data[Teff < 6500]
main_seq = data[Teff >= 6500]
giant = data[(Teff > 6500) & (logg > 3.5)]

ax = plt.axes()
ax.scatter(Teff, logg, s = 1, lw = 0, c = 'r', alpha = 0.9, marker = '.')
ax.set_xlim(8000, 4500)
ax.set_ylim(5.1, 1)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathrm{T_{eff} [K]}$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\mathrm{log_{10}} [g/cm/s^2]}$')
```

[image]

The upper plume is dominated by red giants, to the right of T_eff ~ 6500 is main sequence,
to the left blue horizontal branch stars.

How could I colour the points in those regions of the plot according to their position; such as red for the upper plume, yellow for the main sequence and blue for the blue branch? I've separated the branches into slices from the dataset, but I'm not sure how to plot them on the same axes with different colours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your current code, you can change the `scatter` call to something like this:

```
ax.scatter(blue_branch['Teff'], blue_branch['logg'], s=1, lw=0, c='b', alpha=0.9, marker='.')
ax.scatter(main_seq['Teff'], main_seq['logg'], s=1, lw=0, c='y', alpha=0.9, marker='.')
ax.scatter(giant['Teff'], giant['logg'], s=1, lw=0, c='r', alpha=0.9, marker='.')
```

It's also possible to achieve the same in a single call, by creating an array of colors and filling it in three passes instead of creating three slices of actual data. The approach with slices allows to create a legend in a more straightforward way, in case you need it.